How to Create a PEG.js/peggyjs Rule that Narrows an Existing Rule by Excluding Specific Characters?
Let's suppose I have a rule A:
A = [a-z]+ { return {my: data} }

Is there a way to derive such a rule B which would narrow down A by restricting its scope, e.g.
B = ... !{ return text().match(/b/) } ... A

so that input abcd would match only a? A naïve approach using lookahead assertion doesn't work, as A is already resolved.
